# Apply For Red White Red Card Visa from Sri Lanka

Tags: austria, working-visas

I'm a Sri Lankan with a job offer for Vienna, Austria. I'm just about to apply for my Red White Red Card Visa and wondering about the process. there is no any clear path to apply for the RWR card from Sri Lanka (we don't have an Austrian Embassy or a representative for RWR card visa in Sri Lanka). do we have to apply for this via India (Austrian Embassy in New Delhi) or is there any other specific way to go through this. really appreciate your help with this. Thanks

Comment: I believe this is a question for [Expatriates.SE].